# Net beans 8.0 on MAC OS keeps restarting

Tags: java, netbeans, restart

i have just installed net beans 8.0 but every time i try to close it, it's closed for a second and restart.

also it doesn't run of my application.

What can i do?

Comment: Assuming uninstalling + reinstalling doesn't would I would suggest [filing a bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/)

Comment: thank you for your answer but uninstalling+reinstalling did not work.

Comment: Then a [bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/) is the way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i realized installation is stack when it comes to update.

So, i reinstall it after i close internet connection. During the installation i got no error. But now i got

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660475/netbeans-doesnt-even-run-a-program-that-includes-single-line-code?noredirect=1#comment36343113_23660475

this problem...